# Oauth Google client-side authentication from a pop-up using javascript(coffeescript/jQuery)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, popup, coffeescript, client-side

Im using oauth gem in my rails application.

```
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '1.4.0'
gem "omniauth-google-oauth2"
```

Facebook client-side authentication is working properly. I followed,

http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication

Client-side authentication for google is not working or I couldn't get a handle of it.

I see this coffee script being responsible for facebook client side authentication,

```
jQuery ->
  $('body').prepend('<div id="fb-root"></div>')

  $.ajax
    url: "#{window.location.protocol}//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"
    dataType: 'script'
    cache: true


window.fbAsyncInit = ->
  FB.init(appId: 145280228983243, cookie: true)

  $('#sign_in').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    FB.login (response) ->
      window.location = '/auth/facebook/callback' if response.authResponse

  $('#sign_out').click (e) ->
    FB.getLoginStatus (response) ->
      FB.logout() if response.authResponse
    true
```

**What should i do for google client-side authentication?**

> I just want when a user clicks on "log in with google" a pop-up window
>   should appear and ask for user-id and password and before asking, it
>   should check whether the users information is already available on the
>   browser(client-side) and if available, dont prompt for the user-id and
>   password, go ahead and login.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and it seems that omniauth-google-oauth2 doesn't support client-side authentication this way as the facebook gem does.

The omniauth-facebook gem, when building access_token, checks if the signed request is present and if it's valid, then it uses access_token provided by request.params or cookie. Otherwise it queries access_token from Facebook with the provided authorization_code.

The omniauth-google-oauth2 gem does only the second operation and because redirect_uri must be same on the initial and on the verification request, you cannot use the gem's current version this way.

I have found one fork https://github.com/pivotal-geostellar/omniauth-google-oauth2/tree/client_login with the example http://pivotallabs.com/facebook-and-googleplus-javascript-sdk-sign-in-with-devise-ror/ but it's not secure to read access_token from request.params without validating it on the server-side.

**update**

I found a way to verify access_token by id_token and made a pull request to the gem https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2/pull/50